# Do While Loops in C

Tags: c

I know this is a probably a very simple question but I've asked a few experienced people and they can't figure it out and they don't know why. It's just a simple do while loop that's actually straight out of a book "Absolute Beginner's Guide to C". When it runs and you type `n` for entering more numbers, it keeps running. How do you get it to exit the loop? I'm using XCode on a Mac and it's using C.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
float num1, num2, result;
char choice;
do {
    num1 = num2 = result = 0;
    printf("first number?\n");
    scanf(" %f", &num1);
    printf("second number?\n");
    scanf(" %f", &num2);
    result = num1*num2;
    printf("ans = %.0f\n", result);
    printf("do you want to enter another pair of numbers? (Y/N)\n");
    scanf(" %c", &choice);

} while (choice != 'N' && choice  != '\n');
return 0;
}
```

Comment: You made the extremely serious mistake of not checking the return values of your I/O functions (`scanf`, `printf`). You won't get anywhere in programming if you don't check return values.

Comment: Sorry I'm not sure what you mean... What return value didn't I check? How should I improve it?

Comment: Read the manual for `scanf`. See what it returns, and what assumptions you can make on its effects given its return values.

Comment: Got it. Its working now thanks

Answer (score 4):

It will stop running if you type **N** (`'N'`) or **Enter** (`'\n'`). If you want to stop it typing a lowercase **n** (`'n'`) too, you should write:

```
while (choice != 'N' && choice != 'n' && choice  != '\n');
```

Comment: Remove `choice  != '\n'` as it will never be true.

Answer (score 2):

```
scanf(" %f", &num1);
```

should be

```
scanf("%f", &num1);
```

and check the return value of `scanf()`

```
if(scanf("%f", &num1) != 1)
{
  printf("scanf failed\n");
}
```

When you enter `N` or `\n` you should be able to exit the loop after this

Comment: The change to `scanf("%f", &num1);` is not required. Both the `scanf` do the same thing regardless of the space.

Answer (score -1):

The mistake you had made that is about `scanf` statement. The running code for your program is below:

```
       #include <stdio.h>
       int main() {
       float num1, num2, result;
       char choice;
       do {
           num1 = num2 = result = 0;
           printf("first number?\n");
           scanf("%f", &num1);
           printf("second number?\n");
           scanf("%f", &num2);
           result = num1*num2;
           printf("ans = %.0f\n", result);
           printf("do you want to enter another pair of numbers?  (Y/N)\n");
           scanf("%c", &choice);
           } while (choice != 'N' && choice  != 'n');
           return 0;
           }
```

Comment: why -1 is given for the answer?please at stackoverflow.com give me the reason when you putting -1 on my reply

Comment: Not my down-vote, but it might well be that you've not said anything very different from what the other two answers give, but you submitted your answer an hour and a half after the other two.  You also haven't given a very detailed explanation of the changes you made.  The indentation is a bit erratic too.